# flutter unable to get response from api

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Hello guys i am trying to fetch data from server api , the same is working absolutely fine in postman but i am getting following below exception when i hit from flutter

I/flutter (20104):

## Object Moved

This document may be found [here](https://ss.xysz.com/api/Course/List)

This below is my code

```
 var bodyMap = json.encode(map);

    final response = await client.post(
      "$baseUrl/api/Course/List",
      headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
      body: bodyMap,
    );

    print("##courses coming"+response.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      print("##coming to 201");
      return responseFromJson(response.body);
    }else if(response.statusCode == 400)
    {
      print("##coming to 400---"+response.statusCode.toString());
      print("##coming to 400-body-"+responseFromJson(response.body).toString());
      return responseFromJson(response.body);
    }
    else {
      print("##coming to 200---"+response.body.toString());
      var s=responseFromJson(response.body);
      print("##coming to success-"+s.toString());
      return responseFromJson(response.body);
    }
```

Comment: please paste your exception here

Comment: ---<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
I/flutter (20349): <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://xyz.omansf.com/api/Course/List">here</a></body>

Comment: This site can’t be reached.

Comment: but it works well in postman

Comment: what exception you get ?

Comment: <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HRE. --- this exception

Comment: is the url is exactly same with postman  ?

Comment: yes exactly the same

Comment: please screenshot the postman include the url and the param

Comment: its resolved .. the issue was when server was migrated it took time to respond with changes

Comment: ok,glad to hear that